# Intercepting LINQ to SQL results

Tags: c#, datacontext, devart

I'm attempting to capture query results from linq expressions sent to a DataContext (Devart.Data.Linq). I am able to record the queries by making use of the Log property but have not yet found a way to intercept the IQueryable results.

The intention is to pair the queries and results together, serialize them, and use them later for mocking the data context in a test suite.

All of the Devart.Data.Linq.DataContext methods that look promising (ExecuteQuery, Query) are non-virtual and so I can't override them to store the results. I don't want to record the results at the point in which the linq queries are written as it will be very messy and mean pasting in test related code throughout the application.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why not just iterate the `IQueryable` or use `ToList` to get the results?

Comment: @Hogan My understanding is that the OP wants the generated query which they are getting and the results, so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @juharr (your first question) That would be at the point where the linq query was written. I want to capture the results elsewhere. For instance, my hope was to extend DataContext and somehow capture the results at an intermediate step. Perhaps it is not possible and my question makes no sense.

Comment: @Hogan apologies for confusion. I want the results. The queries are easy enough to get via the Log property. I've amended the question.

Comment: I don't know about this particular provider... but many query providers allow you to get the generated query by doing a `.ToString()` on the `IQueryable`

Comment: @charliemango - in that case juharr's comment makes a lot of sense -- IQueriables are designed to give results, what about those results can't you use?

Comment: You'd have to muck around with the `GetEnumerable` method of whatever `IQueryable` the context returns.  Pretty sure what you want is not going to be possible without access to the source code, or writing a wrapper.

Comment: If you're using Entity Frameworks, the query isn't executed until you make the `ToList()` call you can simply delay that call until you're ready?

Comment: @juharr writing a wrapper was the way to go. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm I wasn't able to delay execution of the query without changing a lot of other things in code. The intention was to intercept at the point of querying.

Comment: If you're using EF, then it doesn't execute until you call a `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault` methods. Not sure what you mean, it doesn't get executed until then.

Comment: Yes I understand, but that alone doesn't help me capture every query expression + query result implicitly. I want to avoid polluting the code with "capture my query" statements everywhere there is a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a roundabout way of intercepting both queries and results through wrapping both the DataContext and the contained IQueryables. This required implementing a custom IQueryable and IQueryProvider. A good example is given at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2010/03/01/tip-55-how-to-extend-an-iqueryable-by-wrapping-it/
Once that was done it was possible to catch the results of queries in the overriden `IQueryProvider.Execute` method. Catching the associated SQL generated by the ORM required tracking the `DataContext.Log` property for changes before and after the query was executed.